# M2.4.2 - Slow Queries consuming the CPU

Tags: magento2, database

I am facing a very bad query that is consuming the database reflecting on the CPU badly, I need some guidance in how I can address it:

```
SELECT
 `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
 `e`.`entity_id`,
 `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
 `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
 IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
 t_d.value,
 t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM
 `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d` 
 INNER JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
 ON e.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 LEFT JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` 
 ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id 
 AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 AND t_s.store_id = ? 
 WHERE
 (
 e.entity_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.attribute_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.store_id = IFNULL(t_s.store_id, ?)
 ) 
 UNION
 ALL SELECT
 `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
 `e`.`entity_id`,
 `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
 `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
 IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
 t_d.value,
 t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM
 `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d` 
 INNER JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
 ON e.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 LEFT JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` 
 ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id 
 AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 AND t_s.store_id = ? 
 WHERE
 (
 e.entity_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.attribute_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.store_id = IFNULL(t_s.store_id, ?)
 ) 
 UNION
 ALL SELECT
 `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
 `e`.`entity_id`,
 `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
 `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
 IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
 t_d.value,
 t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM
 `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d` 
 INNER JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
 ON e.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 LEFT JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` 
 ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id 
 AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 AND t_s.store_id = ? 
 WHERE
 (
 e.entity_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.attribute_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.store_id = IFNULL(t_s.store_id, ?)
 ) 
 UNION
 ALL SELECT
 `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
 `e`.`entity_id`,
 `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
 `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
 IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
 t_d.value,
 t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM
 `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d` 
 INNER JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
 ON e.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 LEFT JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` 
 ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id 
 AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 AND t_s.store_id = ? 
 WHERE
 (
 e.entity_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.attribute_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.store_id = IFNULL(t_s.store_id, ?)
 ) 
 UNION
 ALL SELECT
 `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
 `e`.`entity_id`,
 `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
 `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
 IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
 t_d.value,
 t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM
 `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d` 
 INNER JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
 ON e.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 LEFT JOIN
 `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` 
 ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id 
 AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id 
 AND t_s.store_id = ? 
 WHERE
 (
 e.entity_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.attribute_id IN (?)
 ) 
 AND (
 t_d.store_id = IFNULL(t_s.store_id, ?)
 )
```

Comment: It's profiler report?

Comment: @RohanHapani No, it is mysql slow log.

Comment: Add php code also from where you print sql log.

Comment: any custom indexing added in magento?? if yes then change it to update on save instead of update on scheduled

Comment: @GohilRajesh That is irrelevant :)

Comment: I faced same issue. and fixed by that only.so I just suggested u bro.

Comment: @IbrahimS Did you find any solution to this slow query issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please try run a ANALYZE TABLE on all you Magento2 tables

`mysqlcheck -a -A`

This will force the internal MySQL indexes and innodb stats to be rebuilt for you tables.

This seems to be introduced in a few Magento 2 upgrades which I have performed.